# How to change QPushButton Font Family

Tags: python

How can I change the font family of my qpushbutton. I don't like the default font. SetFont and setStyleheet  seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

```
QFont font = ui->pushButton->font();
font.setPointSize(16);
ui->pushButton->setFont(font);
```

Comment: Thanks  for your reply but I forgot to mention that I am working on a python pyqt4 project and am not using the designer